# State only gets actualized on the second cklick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-state

Basically I want to set the state property of `searchButtonClicked` to true when the user clicks the button. The problem is when the button gets clicked for the first time and when the user has entered smth. `searchButtonClicked` remains false `{textInput: "frw", searchButtonClicked: false}` only on the second click searchButtonClicked gets true.`{textInput: "frw", searchButtonClicked: true}`
What went wrong? Heres the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

class Wikipedia extends Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   
    this.state = {
      textInput:"",
      searchButtonClicked: false
    }

    this.onTextInput=this.onTextInput.bind(this);
    this.onButtonClicked=this.onButtonClicked.bind(this);
  }

 
  onTextInput(event) {
      this.setState({ 
      textInput: event.target.value
     })
      
  }

  onButtonClicked() {
    this.setState({ 
      searchButtonClicked: true
     })

    console.log(this.state);
  }


  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h1> My Wikipedia API App </h1>
      <input type="text"  onChange={this.onTextInput}/>
      <br/>
      <button onClick={this.onButtonClicked}> Search </button>
    </div>
    )
  }


}

export default Wikipedia;
```

Thanks in advance and greetings

Fabian

Comment: `setState` is async function. The changes will not shows immediately. You can pass console in to setState callback or in to render function.

Comment: Try `this.setState({ searchButtonClicked: true }, () => console.log(this.state));`

Comment: Okay you guys are right! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also go with async / await for less nesting:

```
onButtonClicked = async() => {

    await this.setState({ 
        searchButtonClicked: true
    });

    console.log(this.state);
}
```